# How to pass class and its type as a parameter by using generics?

Tags: java, android, generics

I am trying to pass a class and its type as a parameter, but it looks like this is not allowed in java. Does anyone have any idea in order to pass class T or P by using generics? Please check this simple example:

```
    class Car<P> {

    }

    class Sport {

    }

    main() {
       Sport sport = createInstance(Sport.class); // This is fine.
       Car car = createInstance(Car.class); // This is also fine.
       Car<Sport> sportCar = createInstance(Car<Sport>.class) // but this is not allowed. How can I pass "<Sport>" type?
    }  

    public <T> T createInstance(Class<T> classOfT) {
        T instance = classOfT.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

        return instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to type erasure,

```
   Car<Sport> sportCar = createInstance(Car.class)
```

is sufficient. The generic type information `<Sport>` exists only at compile-time, and not at run-time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, it is sufficient, but I recieve warning message:

Unchecked assignment "Car" to "Car<Sport>" 

So, it seems I have to find a way to send P param. I do not just want to surpress warning.

Comment: That's the penalty of using generics. But, if you knew the class at compile-time, you should be using `new` and not reflection …

Comment: Yeah, I cannot create an instance in that method for a reason (which is a long story).   I see. If so, I have to deal with the warning. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I think for your function main(), you can easily fix your problem with the following:

`Car<Sport> sportCar = new Car<>(); // assuming java 8`

I'm not sure if you are getting errors with the `createInstance()` method, but I would say you can remove the Class keyword from the arguments.

Let me know if that helps! If not, holler back!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to create instance in the generic method. I just need to send P and T.

Comment: Oh I see! let me take a closer look then! Sorry I wasn't of more help!

Comment: It's alright. Thanks for your response anyway, but it looks like it is not possible as I was expecting.